# Android-Studio Giraffe broke the gradle-wrapper.jar that called my unit tests

Tags: gradlew, gradle-wrapper

`$ ./gradlew test` stopped working, so I went with this:

```
$ java -Dorg.gradle.appname=gradlew -classpath /home/phlip/projects/app/App/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.jar org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain --project-dir App --console=verbose test
```

It also produces this output:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:testDebugUnitTest'.
> Could not create task ':app:processDebugResources'.
   > Cannot use @TaskAction annotation on method IncrementalTask.taskAction$gradle_core() because interface org.gradle.api.tasks.incremental.IncrementalTaskInputs is not a valid parameter to an action method.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

Of course I shall do none of those dreadful things, because substituting an older `-classpath blah/blah/gradle-wrapper.jar` worked.

So can anyone think of a better fix than me calling `git add` on an obsolete but working `gradle-wrapper.jar` file?